# How to copy\paste selected field to other attribute table in ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, copy

I try to copy this selected field only from attribute table to another attribute table of another layer as is:

[image]

Is there any way to do it without using join tool?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a join? You could also use arcpy and an UpdateCursor, but if you have a join field to match both tables, I don't see the added value of the cursor compared to a join.

Comment: There is no guarantee these will match record for record in the other table without a Join or python script. Also that being a shape length field (parameter) from a geodatabase is automatically calculated and updated in another Geodatabase featureclass.

Comment: can you show me this code please

Comment: BERA is  providing you with a valid solution that involves joining your data via Python without having to do the join.  While this is a valid solution to your question it is far more complicated than just doing a join.  Please address @GISGe question.  Why don't you want to use a join?

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this is a  direct answer:

You have ensure you are in 'editing mode' of the FC/SHP that you want to paste into.
I copy the WHOLE table from the one I am copying from.
Paste into a .xls spreadsheet.
In the spreadsheet, select the column I cant to copy (include the heading.
left-click the column/attribute in the table you want to paste into (this should then select the column).
then Cntrl+v.

Bear in mind this will paste the features in the order from the  spreadsheet. Be sure to 'sort by' in the table you are pasting into so that they match the order.

Comment: michaeltomiak where do i paste it?